# Missing project subtype

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2015

I've installed VS 2015 and all the other software needed to use Xamarin.

When I try and create a project in the option under New Project -> Other Languages -> Visual C# -> iOS, I always get the following error message:

> The project file 'C:\Users...App1.csproj' cannot be opened. There is a
>   missing project subtype.
>   Subtype:'{6BC8ED88-2882-458C-8E55-DFD12B67127B}' is unsupported by
>   this installation.

I've removed all the other addon installs, did a repair on VS and reinstalled addons and I still get this error.

Comment: Did you install all the tools for mobile development and sdk on the VS2015 installation?